# Handling null values in $arrayElement aggregation functions

Tags: aggregation-framework

```
                "safeguard": {
                    $arrayElemAt: [
                        "$join.safe_prevention",
                        0
                    ]
                },
```

I have this aggregation inside my project it works, but it returns either true or null, I need it to return true or false.

```
                "safeguard": {
                    $not: {
                        $eq: [$arrayElemAt: [
                                                "$join.safe_prevention",
                                                0
                                            ]
                        : null]
                    }
                },
```

I have tried this, but it doesn't work, because $eq doesn't accept functions as its first argument, what's the proper way to do this?

Comment: Use `$ifNull` for this

Comment: I can't use $ifNull with $arrayElementAt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not very clear, since I don't see where the `true` is set, but if you want to avoid the null you can use `$ifNull`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      safeguard: {$ifNull: [{$arrayElemAt: ["$join.safe_prevention", 0]}, false]}
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/D0-LIRyqqXP)

If you want to get `true` if there is an item 0 and `false` if there is no such item, you can try:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$set: {
      safeguard: {
        $cond: [
          {$eq: [
              {$ifNull: [{$arrayElemAt: ["$join.safe_prevention", 0]}, false]},
              false
            ]
          }, false, true]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example boolean](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vMLR8hw7Wgc)